# How to say "to die of being frozen"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Example sentence:

> I tugged open the refrigerator. A relatively safe place; I’d never
>   heard of anyone falling inside one and dying __.

What's the correct way of referring to "dying of being frozen"?

Comment: We say "freeze to death".

Comment: The usual idiom is "froze to death" (even though the body may not actually freeze).  This would be death due to [hypothermia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothermia).

Comment: (And, actually, deaths inside refrigerators and freezers were quite common at one time, before laws changed to require them to be openable from the inside.)

Comment: @Hot Licks Really? I've never seen a refrigerator where a human could fit. http://www.stagemyownhome.com/images/fridgewithfood.jpg

Comment: @alex - Really.  Kids especially, but occasionally older, larger people.

Comment: @alex: It was typically kids playing in abandoned fridges and becoming trapped. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrigerator_death

Comment: @Jon As your Wikipedia link points out (and depending on the size of the refrigerator or freezer), it's likely that the person would die of suffocation rather than hypothermia. I realise that doesn't help to answer the question but it might prompt the original poster to ensure that his hapless hero's cause of death seems plausible.

Comment: @GEdgar could make that answer, perhaps.

Comment: Agree the most common expression is "Froze to death",  but if you are looking to fill the blank (...one and dying __), words like [Frozen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frozen) and [Iced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iced) might fit. Also take a look at [Glaciate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glaciate) and [Congealed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congealed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two colloquial phrases you could use here.

**1. Freeze to death**

In your sentence this would be:

> I tugged open the refrigerator. A relatively safe place; I’d never heard of anyone falling inside one and **freezing to death**.

In reality you'd be dead long before your whole body froze. But it's a common phrase, with over 450,000 [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-GB%3AIE-Address&q=%22freezing%20to%20death%22&oq=%22freezing%20to%20death%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l4.7383.8533.0.9173.2.2.0.0.0.0.91.171.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.170...0j0i67k1.Upj26RSWnnw) [hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-GB%3AIE-Address&q=%22freeze%20to%20death%22&oq=%22freeze%20to%20death%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i10i30k1j0i7i30k1l3.67803.68300.0.68649.4.4.0.0.0.0.101.374.3j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.370...0i13k1.JVGKt42qNjs).

**2. Hypothermia**

In your sentence this would be:

> I tugged open the refrigerator. A relatively safe place; I’d never heard of anyone falling inside one and dying **of hypothermia**.

Technically "hypothermia" just means "*subnormal body temperature*" (ref: [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypothermia)). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothermia) defines it as "*a body core temperature below 35.0 °C (95.0 °F)*" and states in a picture caption: "*During Napoleon Bonaparte's retreat from Russia in the winter of 1812, many troops died from hypothermia*".

It doesn't have to be freezing to reduce your body temperature that low, and just because your body temperature gets that low doesn't guarantee you'll die. Although it is possible to die from your body temperature being too low, "hypothermia" is not analogous with "dying of being frozen". But then in a refrigerator it shouldn't get as low as freezing temperatures anyway, so it is probably appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Not *hypothermia*, though. The use of *hypothermia* in the Wiki article refers to the medical condition defined by the term.

Comment: Those who are "frozen to death" may not necessarily have died of hypothermia. And those who die of hypothermia may not have frozen to death. The concepts are similar but quite **different**. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've edited the answer with this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is "hypothermia".

Comment: Have you checked the word in a dictionary?

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).